# Failed to distribute Xamarin.iOS application through Microsoft App Center

Tags: ios, xamarin, appcenter

I have developed a Xamarin Forms application targeting Android and iOS and I want to distribute the app through Microsoft App Center. The Android versions are distributed fine to connected groups and users. iOS versions they do get installed normally in the devices but when launched they show the splash screen for two seconds and terminate. The application runs fine to simulators and to usb-connected devices using Automatic Provisioning. I have repeated many times all the steps for the provisioning and signing of the application but with no success. I am not sure if the problem is with provisioning of the application or with building and linking within App Center. From the log in the device I see SIGABORT is called but do not know what causes that. Since it has been a few months that I am struggling with problem every help or idea is welcome.

Comment: you need to add some instrumentation to your app.  AppCenter has crash reporting and logging services you can use

Comment: would that give me some more profit than the log that I can see in the actual device?

Comment: possibly, but I can't guarantee it.